# ggplot: change values shown in legend for point size aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

When I use the size aesthetic with `geom_point()` in ggplot, I often want to broaden the range of values shown in the default legend. In this plot, for example, there are a couple of points with a value of `hp` much smaller than the smallest value shown in the legend (100), and the reader may have trouble guessing what that value might be:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = hp)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

How can I alter the legend to show sizes corresponding to values I choose, e.g. `c(50, 150, 250)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scale_size_continuous`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = hp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_continuous(range  = c(0.1, 10), 
                        limits = c(0, 500), 
                        breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 200, 400)
```

[image]

If you want to emphasise differences within the range (whilst losing the area-proportionality that makes such plots more 'honest'), you can use a transformation too:

```r
sq <- scales::trans_new("squared", function(x) x^2, sqrt)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = hp)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "deepskyblue3") +
  scale_size_continuous(range  = c(0.1, 10), 
                        limits = c(0, 350), 
                        breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350),
                        trans  = sq) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This could do the job, thank you. I wondered if one can easily (i.e. without guessing the default scale) change the legend without changing the appearance of the figure.

Comment: It looks like you can if you just specify the `breaks`.

Comment: @AndyEggers yes, you can do that, although you can only specify breaks within the range of the data if you don't also specify limits - perhaps that's what you want though.

Comment: Great answer Alan! Small note: `scale_size_area()` is exactly the use-case for the latter part of your answer.